# Allocate the resource of some threads to a global resource such that there is no concurrency(using only mutexes)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, operating-system, posix

The summary of the problem is the following: Given a global resource of size N and M threads with their resource size of Xi (i=1,M) , syncronize the threads such that a thread is allocated,it does its stuff and then it is deallocated.

The main problem is that there are no resources available and the thread has to wait until there is enough memory. I have tried to "block" it with a while statement, but I realized that two threads can pass the while loop and the first to be allocated can change the global resource such that the second thread does not have enough space, but it has already passed the conditional section.

```
//piece of pseudocode
...
int MAXRES = 100;

// in thread function
{
   while (thread_res  > MAXRES);

   lock();
   allocate_res(); // MAXRES-=thread_res;
   unlock();

  // do own stuff

  lock()
  deallocate(); // MAXRES +=thread_res;
  unlock();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a robust solution you need something more.  As you noted, you need a way to wait until the condition ' there are enough resources available for me ', and a proper mutex has no such mechanism.  At any rate, you likely want to bury that in the allocator, so your mainline thread code looks like:

```
....
   n = Allocate()
   do stuff
   Release(n)
....
```

and deal with the contention:

```
int navail = N;
int Acquire(int n) {
     lock();
     while (n < navail) {
          unlock();
          lock();
     }
     navail -= n;
     unlock();
     return n;
}
void Release(int n) {
     lock();
     navail += n;
     unlock();
}
```

But such a *spin waiting* system may fail because of priorities -- if the highest priority thread is spinning, a thread trying to Release may not be able to run.   Spinning isn't very elegant, and wastes energy.   You could put a short nap in the spin, but if you make the nap too short it wastes energy, too long and it increases latency.

You really want a signalling primitive like semaphores or condvars rather than a locking primitive.  With a semaphore, it could look impressively like:

```
Semaphore *sem;
int Acquire(int n) {
     senter(sem, n);
     return n;
}
int Release(int n) {
     sleave(sem, n);
     return n;
}
void init(int N) {
     sem = screate(N);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Revised to use System V semaphores, which provides the ability to specify arbitrary 'checkout' and 'checkin' to the semaphore value. Overall logic the same.

Disclaimer: I did not use System V for few years, test before using, in case I missed some details.

```
int semid ;
   // Call from main
do_init() {
   shmkey = ftok(...) ;
   semid = shmget(shmkey, 1, ...) ;
   // Setup 100 as max resources.
   struct sembuf so ;
   so.sem_num = 0 ;
   so.sem_op = 100 ;
   so.sem_flg = 0 ;
   semop(semid, &so, 1) ;
}

   // Thread work
do_thread_work() {
   int N = <number of resources>
   struct sembuf so ;
   so.sem_num = 0;
   so.sem_op = -N ;   
   so.sem_flg = 0 ;
   semop(semid, &so, 1) ;

   ... Do thread work

   // Return resources
   so.sem_op = +N ;
   semop(semid, &so, 1) ;
}
```

As per: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/semop.html, this will result in atomic checkout of multiple items.

Note: the ... as sections related to IPC_NOWAIT and SEM_UNDO, not relevant to this case.

- If sem_op is a negative integer and the calling process has alter permission, one of the following shall occur:

  - If semval(see ) is greater than or equal to the absolute value of sem_op, the absolute value of sem_op is subtracted from semval. ...
  - ...
  - If semval is less than the absolute value of sem_op ..., semop() shall increment the semncnt associated with the specified semaphore and suspend execution of the calling thread until one of the following conditions occurs:

    - The value of semval becomes greater than or equal to the absolute value of sem_op. When this occurs, the value of semncnt associated with the specified semaphore shall be decremented, the absolute value of sem_op shall be subtracted from semval and, ... .

Comment: As far as I know , a semaphore decrements its value with one unit at each sem_wait call. Does it really help me in this situation where I have to decrement a specific value for each thread?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I mixed System V semaphores with unnamed semaphores. System V `semops` allow atomic 'checkout' and 'checkin' of arbitrary count on semaphores created with `semget`. I'll revise my example later